# Matrix Taylor series

Tags: matrices, taylor-expansion

I'm just wondering why
$$(A+\epsilon)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}\epsilon A^{-1}+\mathcal O(\epsilon^2).$$

Can someone please show me the steps? Like in the second term, why is $\epsilon$ sandwiched between the $A^{-1}$'s? Thank you!!

Comment: Did you mean $(A + \epsilon \color{red}{I})^{-1}$? Also, if $\epsilon$ is a scalar, then it does not need to be sandwiched between the $A^{-1}$'s.

Comment: Yes, and $\epsilon$ is not a scalar.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: One way to approach this problem is to just pull out $A^{-1}$, so $(A+\epsilon)^{-1}=A^{-1}(1+\epsilon A^{-1})^{-1}$. Then you can use the formula for $(1-B)^{-1}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is $(A + \epsilon)^{-1} = [A(I + A^{-1}\epsilon )]^{-1} = (I + A^{-1}\epsilon )^{-1}A^{-1}$  and $(I + A^{-1}\epsilon )^{-1} = I - A^{-1}\epsilon  + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$.

Comment: Thank you. What is the second order $\epsilon$ term?